# What's wrong with this PHP and/or MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning PHP and MySQL at the moment. I am attempting a simple page where I can submit a short message, and retrieve a message from the server (just a random number for this particular case).

```
<?php

$success = false;

require_once '../../../phpIncludes/mysqlIncludes.php';
require_once '../../../phpIncludes/iphandler.php';
$creds = new MySQLLoginCredentials;
$con = $creds->ConnectToDB();

mysql_select_db("testDB", $con);

$userMsg = trim($_POST['msg']);
//The simple version for 128 Characters from the beginning of the string
$userMsg = substr($userMsg,0,128);
$userMsg = filter_var($userMsg, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,!FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);

$ip = encode_ip( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );

$time = time();

$returnMsg = "". rand() . "";

$userAgent = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
//Trim to 256 since that is largest db can hold
$userAgent = substr($userAgent,0,256);
$userAgent = filter_var($userAgent, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//Debug 
echo "Time : " . $time . "<br>"
. " IP: " . $ip . " | " . decode_ip($ip) . "<br>"
. " UserAgent: " . $userAgent . "<br>"
. " Msg: " . $userMsg . "<br>"
. " Return: " . $returnMsg . "<br>";

$sql = "INSERT INTO TestMessageTbl (TimeStamp, IPAddress, ClientInfo, IncMsg, OutMsg)
VALUES ('" . $time . "', " . $ip . ", " . $userAgent . ", " . $userMsg . ", " . $returnMsg .")";

$success = mysql_query($sql, $con);

if($success == false)
{
    echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
}

echo $returnMsg;

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The output is:

```
<i>Time : 1356919336
IP: * | *
UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
Msg: 
Return: 743166102
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.' at line 2743166102</i>
```

The table looks like this:

```
UID bigint(20) unsigned, AUTO_INCREMENT
TimeStamp bigint(20) unsigned
IPAddress varchar(32) utf8_general_ci
ClientInfo varchar(256) utf8_general_ci
IncMsg varchar(128) utf8_general_ci
OutMsg varchar(128) utf8_general_ci
```

I manually transcribed from mysql, incase there's typos...

What struck me immediately as odd was the very large line number for the error. What's up with that?

P.S. I know as it stands, $msg will be blank

Comment: Well crap, as soon as I posted this, I realized the issue was the quotes:
$sql = "INSERT INTO TestMessageTbl (TimeStamp, IPAddress, ClientInfo, IncMsg, OutMsg)
 VALUES (" . $time . ", '" . $ip . "', '" . $userAgent . "', '" . $userMsg . "', '" . $returnMsg ."')";
works

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is outdated (for years now), not maintained anymore and will is marked as "deprecated" in 5.5. use `PDO_MySQL`, or `MySQLi` instead. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Comment: Ah, thanks KingCrunch. Any suggestions on which is better to use?

Comment: Internally both use the same engine. `PDO` is an abstraction layer and thus it's easier to change the dbs later, when needed. On the other hand `MySQLi` supports some MySQL-features, that `PDO_MySQL` doesn't, but it's hard to tell, if one needs them, or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap all your values with simple quote

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TestMessageTbl (TimeStamp, IPAddress, ClientInfo, IncMsg, OutMsg)
VALUES ('" . $time . "', '" . $ip . "', '" . $userAgent . "', '" . $userMsg . "', '" . $returnMsg ."')";
```